# What is template and how and where to create it in gsp?

Tags: grails

In the following what is a `template`? Where do I create it and how is it used?

```
def RenderDemo = {

    //Render text to response
    render "hellooooo"

    //Render text for specified content type/ encoding
    render (text: "<strong><h1><marquee>Akshay</marquee></h1></strong>" , contentType: "text/html")

    //Render a Template to the response for the specified model...
    def theShining = [title: "The Shining" , auther : "king"]

    render(template: "RenderDemo" , model: [book : theShining])

}
```

Comment: they go in your views: http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/grails-goodness-render-gsp-views-and.html

Comment: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.11/guide/theWebLayer.html#viewsAndTemplates

Answer (score 3):

A template is a partial GSP or a fragment of a GSP. It's intended to be reused. Just like any other GSP it belongs in the `grails-app/views/` directory structure. All templates have a filename that begins with an underscore `_`. So in your example the template would be: `grails-app/views/render/_renderDemo.gsp`.

I highly recommend you read the [official documentation on views and templates](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#viewsAndTemplates) that explains why you would use a template as well as providing you with even more details about templates in general.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. now i got the idea about what is template. But i have a little bit confusion about where to place it in gsp. can you please give me an simple example on it so it will be clear that where to place the template  in gsp and how to place it...

Comment: That depends on the kind of problem you are trying to solve. Templates can be used in a lot of ways. Ranging from partial page fragments which get loaded/updated/refreshed/whatever via AJAX or simply as a manner to encapsulate rendering of an item within a list which you want to reuse. What problem are you trying to solve? That would be another question you should post. Post what problem you are trying to solve, and what issues you are having with templates trying to solve that problem. To explain all the ways templates can be used would require me reading the documentation for you. (:

Comment: Thank you Joshua. Actually i just started to learn grails. I am trying to use a render method with the template attribute in controller. But actually dont know how it works and how to catch the param in view when we render from the controller